# tengo que sacar las vocales de una cadena e imprimirlas ordenadamente y sin que se repitan las vocales

Tags: c

hasta ahora solo he conseguido sacar las vocales mas no se como hacer que no se repita
esto es lo que llevo y ya no se me ocurre nada :c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define LONG_MAX 51

char encuentraVocales(char frase[]); 

int main(){

char frase[LONG_MAX];

  printf("Vocales en una frase");
  printf("\nFrase: ");
  gets(frase);//leo la frase
  printf("Vocales: ");
  encuentraVocales(frase); //imprimo las vocales

  return 0;    
}
```

esta es la funcion para sacar las vocales

```
char encuentraVocales(char frase[]){

char vocales[LONG_MAX];

  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(frase); i++){
      if((frase[i] == 'a' || frase[i] == 'e' || frase[i] == 'i' || frase[i] == 'o' || frase[i] == 'u')){ //busco las vocales dentro de la frase
        vocales[i]=frase[i];//paso las vocales a la cadena vocales
        printf("%c",vocales[i]); // **aqui imprimiria todas las vocales**
      }         
   }
}
```

intente varias formas de eliminar las vocales repetidas pero no lo logre espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: *"intente varias formas de eliminar las vocales repetidas"*. Seria bueno que compartieras esos intentos tambien. Yo lo que te recomendaria es crear un array de booleanos, inicializarlos a `false`, e ir marcando con `true` las vocales que te vas encontrando. O puedes crear una cadena, inicializada a `\0`, e ir añadiendo las vocales que encontraste, luego puedes buscar en la cadena si ya las encontraste antes.

Answer (score 0):

La solución es tan simple como crear una función que se encarge de verificar si la letra ya se encuentra en tu array y en base a eso agregarás la letra al array o no.

```c
char encuentraVocales(char frase[]){

  char vocales[LONG_MAX];
  int v = 0; 
  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(frase); i++){
      if((frase[i] == 'a' || frase[i] == 'e' || frase[i] == 'i' || frase[i] == 'o' || frase[i] == 'u')){ //busco las vocales dentro de la frase
        if(verificar(vocales,frase[i])){ // si nos devuelve 1
            vocales[v]=frase[i]; //agregamos
            v++;
        }
      }         
   }
   
   for(int i = 0; i< v; i++){
       printf("%c",vocales[i]); // **aqui imprimiria todas las vocales**
   }
}

int verificar(char arr[], char letra){
    // recorremos el array 
    for(int i = 0; i< sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); i++){
        if(arr[i]==letra){ // si hay coincidencia
            return 0; //retornamos 0, que sería como un false
        }
    }
    return 1; //retornamos 1, que sería como un true
}
```

La variable `v` la he creado con el fin de ir añadiendo los elementos correctamente, ya que si hacías `vocales[i]=frase[i]` y la variable `i` tenía el valor 10, la letra se agregaba en la posición 10 del array vocales y dejaba las otras posiciones vacías, es decir, agregaba los valores de forma discontinua, pero al usar una variable aparte estamos agregando los valores de forma continua.

Lo único que faltaría seria ordenar las vocales, pero eso te lo dejo a ti ya que es bastante fácil, lo puedes hacer tu mismo *desde 0* o usar algunas funciones de la librería string.